# What kind of seeds/pods are these?

Tags: seeds, germination, tropical

I purchased these on the WISH app. They were under $1 and advertised as Monstera Seeds. I knew 100% that these were NOT monstera seeds, but had to snag them to try to figure out what they are. At first glance, they look to be bamboo - but I’m still not solid with that. Any guesses on what these could be?

[image: seeds]

Comment: Need more detailed info. Is this a samara type seed (like ash/maple tree for example) where the seed is integrated into the tip of a wing designed to let the seed flutter in the wind as it falls? If it is a pod, crack one open and what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

Those seeds really look like American Tuliptree [(Liriodendron tulipera)](https://growstudio1.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/tulip-tree-seed.jpg) seeds. It's very strange that someone would mistake them for monstera.